# Are there techniques to mathematically compute the amount of searching in greedy graph searching?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bigdata

I have developed a greedy graph search algorithm and made some optimizations. However, its performance varies depending on the parameters I use. I am keen to create a module that can compute the optimal parameter settings to enhance the efficiency of my algorithm. Are there any techniques available to precisely analyze the amount of searching involved in greedy graph searching (approximately exact)? I prefer not to rely on "time complexity" analysis as it may not provide sufficient precision for my specific problem.

I want to build a module that can compute the optimal parameter settings to enhance the efficiency of my algorithm.

Comment: I strongly doubt anyone can answer this. Nearly no information here! Algorithm? Parameters? We need more details

Comment: Indeed the information makes it harder to answer this. You could do some sort of monte carlo simulation, were you input some distribution of your parameter settings. And try to measure performance on queries you find / think are important. Your search algoirthim would need to be deterministic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am sorry for my rough question. I am trying to do a greedy beam search in muti-heads way, may be just like the "MS-BFS", my target is to find k results with highest score. The code is just as simple as you think (from more than one source to start). But sometimes it not work, which made me so confused...